# How to control the shutdown event?

Tags: c, winapi

When power button is pressed,shutdown event command is to be given to external sub-systems. For this i have identified `GetProcessShutdownParameters()` and `SetProcessShutdownParameters()`, is there any other way to get the shutdown event command?

Comment: This is definitely not `C`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh um, why?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can you show me the mention of C++ in the question?

Comment: Are you asking about detecting when the user wants to shut down their computer? If so you want [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sorry. don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I do not understand the question at all. You ask, "Is there any other way to get the shutdown event command?" What exactly do you mean by that. Please make your question more clear.